How are NanoLED and MicroLED computer screens designed differently?
I have asked the following question in SuperUser.SE. If I asked the question on this site would it be closed (I wouldn't cross-post the question would exist only on one site either here or there)?

What is the difference between NanoLED and MicroLED computer screens is it just a marketing gimmick?

The NanoLED trademark seems to indicate that the issue is probably marketing, and not different engineering or materials: 


I don't see a difference since both are allegedly self-emmissive and turn electricity into light
Other than the different emmiter name, I can't see anything different.




I think the question is a question of design (probably circuit design too since panels are a circuit of LEDs) because the differences between these 2 tecnologies may be due to design as suggested by [Mokubai][2] when they said

[just look closely at the image. You can clearly see the difference
just by looking at the LED stages. One has single colour elements, the
other shows a lot of little dots.][3]

I could think of the generic tags
Mechanical Engineering, Electrical Engineering, Materials, Chemical Engineering, Design.
I could probably change a couple of the above to add optics and material science.

Did you ever post this to the Engineering SE?
The answer is: the NanoLED is utilizing electrically pumped quantum dots - electrical current directly energizes the quantum dots.  This is higher efficiency than a backlight optically energizing the quantum dots.  From flatpanelshd.com "Todays displays that use quantum dots in some form are so-called photoluminescent meaning that the QDs absorb light and convert it (for example blue light converted into red or green, as in QD-OLED) whereas electroluminescent quantum dots convert electricity into light, no separate light emitting diodes required."

@Demis I wanted first to ask if it would be on topic so as not to get my question closed as off topic. I also wanted to ask SuperUser.SE moderators to migrate the question. They didn't care about it so I needed to go around asking where the question would be on-topic (possible recipients for a migration). They were idle (I see abuse/misuse of power).

Yes I see that you have been getting a bit of a bureaucratic runaround - so I'm just answering your question directly for now!

@Demis I will need clarification on that. I didn't understand much. I am going to formulate a question on Engineering. I am annoyed at the "bureaucratic runaround" (not quitte the euphemism since my situation was blatant abuse of power they were just sitting idle instead of looking if it could migrated somewhere).

"abuse of power" on a volunteer free website is really a pretty small amount of power - give them a break and don't worry about it too much. But I agree, the mod on EE.SE is not being very helpful - they could have moved it to Eng.SE for you. On the other hand, in Sept they have told you below to post on the Engineering SE, so go ahead and do that, and the problem would have been solved.

@Demis The problem was on SuperUser. The problem would have been solved. I have a question that was deleted (which wouldn~t have happened if it was migrated).

This would be fine to ask on the Electrical Engineering or Engineering stack exchanges.

Would it really be fine to ask in Electrical Engineering.SE?

It's decided by user votes. As a participant there, I'd say probably yes. It's not a big deal to just try.

@Drew - Hi, FYI the OP has already asked (multiple times) on the EE.SE Meta and has been told that the question would not be on-topic, if asked on EE.SE. || It's disappointing that they are asking you about another site, when they have already asked directly on the EE.SE Meta!

@Stephie I think calling it off topic for EE is also a reasonable call.

If it's off topic on EE then it's not on topic anywhere else on SE except maybe general Engineering.  (This may be indeed an EE problem though - my univ does this kind of photonics research in the EE and Materials depts.)  This is a common problem I find with microelectronics and microfabrication - they're so interdisciplinary there just is no good SE site for them.  See, for example, one possibly remedy I suggested here: https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/686/new-microfabrication-tag

Try asking on the general engineering stack exchange. Definitely on topic there.

@Demis https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/62257/how-are-nanoled-and-microled-computer-screens-designed-differently
