New Microfabrication tag
I work at an open-use lab helping people make microchips of various types.
An issue we come across fairly regularly is that there is no place to ask question on this interdiciplinary, and cutting-edge/complex field. There is a large international community around this kind of work, and we currently ask questions via email, or on some non-ideal sites such as ResearchGate; or here are two questions on Meta SE asking where to ask about this topic: one, two.
Since SE Engineering has a "machining" tag, and that is most similar in scope to a microchip 'fab (I consider a microfab basically a machine shop where you can machine things smaller than a drill-bit), I would like to propose a microfabrication tag on SE Engineering.
Synonyms include nanofabrication, and related but not synonyms include microelectronics (means electronics only, discounting microfluidics or optics), nanotechnology (often means beakers and chemistry or materials, not wafer-level machining).

Relevant SE questions
Here is one answer I submitted listing the various SE sites microfab questions currently get spread across (Phys/Chem/Electrical/Eng).
Below are some posts that could possibly be tagged "microfabrication".  I apologize it turns out there were a lot, and sorry if there are duplicates, this took a good amount of manual search filtering. Not exhaustive, but I was trying to be selective.
Engineering SE:  "microfabrication" or "microelectronics" or closely related:

How are NanoLED and MicroLED computer screens designed differently?
How feasible is it to build a benchtop semiconductor protoyping fabrication set up?
Why is the donor level in a semiconductor called a "level"?
Bonding Semiconductors to PCB
Best software for 3D modeling and simulation semiconductors?
So even though the raw materials of semiconductors are cheap why is their cost so high and why don't we use conductor for the same job?
Why do transport containers for wafers open clockwise?
P-N junction depletion region
Is there an instrument that can measure thickness of an object through strain?
"bubbles" forming after heating my Thin film transistors
Why does a hole have greater energy than valence electrons?
Can a semi-conductor cooler be powerful enough for a room?
How to measure resistivity of a given sheet of material?
Why do inorganic LEDs wear out?
Breakdown voltage of electronic devices
Are DVD laser diodes single transverse mode?
Why do monocrystalline solar cells have rounded/cropped edges?
What is micro-electromechanical systems (MEMS)?
How are electronics hardened against extreme accelerations?
Why do some semiconductor devices have a minimum voltage requirement?
Working mechanism of photovoltic cells
Units for plasma etching of circuits: A (with degree symbol)/min
How are components printed onto chips in lithography?
What is the difference between NIL and hot embossing?
Improving PMMA adhesion on Gallium Arsenide wafer pieces
Why resolution of photolithography evolved gradually?
How to make a conductive paint over PDMS?
Can graphene really be made in a modest lab at home?
Can be used a lab on a chip device as a nuclear fusion device?
AutoCAD: Help with exporting micrometer details to PDF
Are cameras' CCDs just elaborate tiny solar cells?

Chemistry SE:

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/109887/how-can-i-prevent-my-spin-coated-silica-thin-film-from-cracking-when-i-heat-it-u/109889#109889
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/160397/why-use-diamond-like-carbon-instead-of-diamond/160415#160415
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33671/is-there-a-selective-wet-etch-of-bi2o3-bismuth-oxide?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C50.8471
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/162624/how-to-remove-graphite-substrate-of-boron-carbide-coating/162625?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C22.2447#162625
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19618/how-is-the-crystal-direction-important-for-etching-silicon-surfaces/20558?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C20.5350#20558
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/101273/what-happens-to-chromium-as-cr2o7-in-the-plasma-of-the-icp?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C69.8497
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/26875/etching-a-screen-protector-film/26888?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C29.3398#26888
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4381/selective-etchant-for-al2o3-does-not-etch-al-cu-zn-sn?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C62.6033
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/44671/is-there-a-chemical-that-will-etch-antimony-but-not-stainless-steel
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/64565/how-do-you-make-photoresist-photohardening-paint?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C53.3165
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/58285/what-would-happen-if-i-mixed-positive-and-negative-photoresists?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C42.5148
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/110584/are-all-lift-off-resist-negative-photoresists?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C28.7533
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32060/pmma-cross-link-temperature?r=SearchResults&s=9%7C21.2894
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/146741/removing-denatured-crystalbond?r=SearchResults&s=12%7C17.7086
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/50234/etching-ito-on-pet-without-damage?r=SearchResults&s=15%7C13.6426
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/150291/what-non-toxic-light-sensitive-materials-do-not-burn-away-at-high-heat/150307?r=SearchResults&s=19%7C9.3117#150307
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/169672/silicon-crystal-orientation/169679#169679
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4354/lithography-is-isopropanol-a-developer-and-or-a-stopper?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C55.6846
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/46371/solvent-for-norland-optical-adhesive?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C30.8393

I think most electroplating questions: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=electroplating
Physics SE:

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/505803/why-should-the-resolution-of-photolithography-follow-the-pattern-described-in-mo/505830?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C19.6983#505830
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/158586/wavelength-used-in-manufacturing-of-integrated-circuits-ic/158694?r=SearchResults&s=5%7C16.1990#158694
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/585595/is-making-a-laser-diode-at-a-home-workshop-impossible?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C37.8410
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/91541/are-phase-specific-masks-ever-used-in-the-context-of-double-exposure-lithograp?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C51.4963
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/91759/the-resolution-limit-for-lithography-in-practice?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C43.1639
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/80615/smallest-minimum-feature-size-possible-for-transistors-printed-by-photolithograp?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C39.7307
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/723417/why-do-we-use-tin-in-extreme-ultraviolet-euv-lithography?r=SearchResults&s=4%7C38.5536
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/18390/focusing-laser-off-axis-illumination-diffraction-limit?r=SearchResults&s=5%7C35.6877
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/350454/any-differences-between-critical-dimension-size-and-resolution-for-an-optical-ob?r=SearchResults&s=6%7C29.4125
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/397664/which-experimental-procedures-exist-for-determining-the-elemental-composition-of?r=SearchResults&s=7%7C27.6585
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/789664/why-do-logic-ics-only-have-one-transistor-layer/789669?r=SearchResults&s=18%7C15.5998#789669
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/559397/why-does-plasma-cleaning-etching-takes-longer-time-to-be-effective-when-there?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C65.9596
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/430948/rf-sputtering-where-comes-the-target-self-bias-voltage-from/612763?r=SearchResults&s=6%7C30.6812#612763

These might better categorized as "Microelectronics" (related but not identical):

search for "semiconductor" https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=semiconductor
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/692150/semiconductors-lattice-scattering-and-impurity-scattering?r=SearchResults&s=4%7C29.2758
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/746575/semiconductor-band-gap?r=SearchResults&s=4%7C43.2568
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/767682/semiconductor-laser?r=SearchResults&s=5%7C43.0969
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/776968/carrier-concentration-on-forward-biased-pn-junction?r=SearchResults&s=5%7C27.3207
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/129188/diffusion-and-drift-currents-in-a-pn-junction?r=SearchResults&s=6%7C26.8780
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/160881/electron-gas-theory-of-a-metal-drude-model-intuition?r=SearchResults&s=7%7C26.4518
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/302030/diffusion-current-density-in-a-semiconductor-a-cm2?r=SearchResults&s=8%7C24.8930
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/588173/is-collector-current-depends-on-width-of-base-and-vcb-in-forward-active-mode-c?r=SearchResults&s=9%7C24.1912
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/160886/why-do-electron-and-hole-mobilities-decrease-with-temperature?r=SearchResults&s=10%7C24.1912
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/165251/internal-resistor-in-a-diode?r=SearchResults&s=11%7C24.1912
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/581048/a-proof-for-why-the-minority-charge-carrier-concentration-along-the-x-axis-in-a?r=SearchResults&s=13%7C22.3385
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/153649/ohmic-contacts-in-a-diode-metal-semiconductor-junction-contact-difference-of?r=SearchResults&s=15%7C18.3512
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/150494/graded-semiconductors-hole-concentration-function-of-x?r=SearchResults&s=17%7C17.6835
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/127654/ohms-law-drude-model/127693?r=SearchResults&s=28%7C10.6824#127693
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/226955/textbook-recommendations-for-electrical-circuits-and-electronics/227709?r=SearchResults&s=29%7C10.6824#227709


Please note that tags cannot be created preemptively without questions. Consider listing  existing questions that may be worthy the tag.

I have added a list of potential questions that could use one of the above tags.  Sorry for the mess, it turns out there were quite a lot!

That's a lot on Engineering.SE, though questions on other SE sites are irrelevant because they're moderated by their own community though.

Ah - perhaps my answer to this question pertains as well then: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315710/where-to-ask-questions-pertaining-to-microfabrication/402880#402880

FYI, I suspect the Phys and Chem Q's may end up here if the microfab/microelectronics tags existed.
